# Location Services not updating heading on iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad, core-location

I've just started work on a navigation app and have hit a wall very early.  I am trying to get magnetometer data but for some reason, the location manager is not sending me the data via the delegate call.  I am getting location updates but not heading updates.  I've read all the documentation and just can't figure it out... It's a simple thing, which means I am probably missing something simple. Here is the code I am using to initialize the location manager: (Note, I am using an iPad 3 with 4G, so it does have the GPS chipset.  Probably doesn't matter but I should also mention that I am using ARC.)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if (!self.locationManager) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
        self.locationManager.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
        NSLog(@"Start updating heading.");
    }
}

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

}

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was not crazy... After banging my head on the wall over this for hours, I thought hey, maybe it's not me, maybe it's the iPad... Sure enough, a reboot of the iPad solved my problem... If you are having the same issue, give the old girl a reboot....